# Is equilibrium potential relative?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrochemistry

If you have a half cell reaction, let's say: $Zn$ electrode and ($SO_4^{2-}$ and $Zn^{2+}$) solution

The solution will get more and more postive and the electrode more and more negative until $\approx 0.74\, V$ potential is reached and the reaction halts.

Edit: In a galvanic cell, the solution will stay neutral (salt bridge).

But I have a doubt. Let's say you have an external source that makes the solution more negative. Can the reaction now continue and the electrode becomes more negative too? Or is my reasoning wrong? (I have been trying for a week to understand batteries in series.)

TLDR: Is there a maximum of how many electrons can the electrode accept and the reactions halt?